# XPath query not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath

Hello i making HttpWebResponse and getting the HtmlPage with all data that i need for example table with date info that i need to save them to array list and save it to xml file

Example of html Page

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
    <tr class="even">
    <td class="padding5 sorting_1">
    <span class="DateHover" sort="14/03/18/22/56" title="18.03.14" ref="18.03.14">18.03.14</span>
    </td>
    <td class="CellStyleDefaultText">
    <span class="transSpan">Info</span>
    </td>
    <td class="CellStyleDefaultText" title="UserNumber123">UserNumber123</td>
    <td class="CellStyleSignedNumber floatopHomePage">
    <span title="701,554.23 ">701,554.23 </span>
    </td>
    <td class="CellStyleAmount CellStyleAmountNew">
    <div title="-3354999.71">-3354999.71</div>
    </td>
    <td class="CellStyleDetails CCMoreDetailsTd">
    <span> 17.03.14 Info</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Ok the first span with dateTime i got

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='DateHover']"))
```

span  with info

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='transSpan']"))
```

and then i stuck  to get UserNumber123 i did this

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='CellStyleDefaultText']"))
```

but it returns me span transSpan as  well because it in td

and all others td CellStyleSignedNumber,CellStyleAmount,CellStyleDetails i can't get.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply mention the attribute name to select element that has particular attribute set. So you can try to get `UserNumber123` this way :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='CellStyleDefaultText' and @title]")
```

Above XPath means, select `<td>` element that has title attribute and hass class attribute value equals 'CellStyleDefaultText'.

For the rest `<td>`, try to use XPath `contains()` function, for example :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[contains(@class,'CellStyleSignedNumber')]")
```

**UPDATE :**

Responding the latter part of your comment, if you intend to get `<td>` that has child `<span>`element, you can add the criteria as simple as following :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[span and contains(@class,'CellStyleSignedNumber')]")
```

Comment: but title UserNumber123 is not static it dynamic in the next tr title is gona be UserNumber456 and ("//td[contains(@class,'CellStyleSignedNumber')]") will select two td because i have two td's with this class but one  with span and another not

Comment: 1. added explanation about the first code snippet to clarify. I didn't hardcode anything about `UserNumber123` in the XPath, so what is the concern? 2. check **UPDATE** section